# Error when using Netbeans External Terminal on Netbeans 8.1/8.2

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

When I try to compile a program using External Terminal it gives the following error:

> Unable to find any valid shell. It is needed for execution in an
>   external terminal. Will start in OutputWindow

If I use the default terminal it works just fine. Same error using Netbeans 8.1 or Netbeans 8.2....